# Find $\lim \sup A_n$ and $\lim \inf A_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

**Question:** Let $\Omega = R^2. A_n$ is the interior of a circle with center at $\left\{\frac{(-1)^n}{n},0 \right\} $ at radius 1. 
Find $\lim \sup A_n$ and $\lim \inf A_n$?

**My answer** is the following;
Let $\Omega = R^2$

As we know, $\lim\sup A_n =\{W: W\in A_n \ \mathrm{for} \ \mathrm{infinite} \ \mathrm{ n}\}$

$\lim\inf A_n =\{W: W\in A_n \ \mathrm{for} \ \mathrm{finite} \ \mathrm{ n}\}$

In this question, there exists a circle with center  at $\left\{\frac{(-1)^n}{n},0 \right\} $ at radius 1.

$X^2 + Y^2 =1 \rightarrow x^2 + y^2 =1 \rightarrow (\cos\theta)^2+(\sin\theta)^2 =1 $

[image]

let $n=1$, there exists a circle with  $(-1,0)$ at radius 1.

$(x-h)^2 +(y-k)^2  =r^2$

$h=1, k=0, r=1$

$(x+1)^2 +(y-0)^2=1^2$

[image]

let n=2, there exists a circle with $(1/2, 0)$ at radius 1

$(x-1/2)^2 +(y-0)^2=1^2$

[image]

$n=3 \rightarrow (-1/2, 0)$ radius=1

$n=4 \rightarrow (1/4, 0)$

and so on...

> > $\lim\inf A_n =\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\lt 1\}$
> >
> > $\lim\sup A_n =\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\le 1\} - \{(0,1), (0,-1)\}$

what i dont understand is a point in  the last gray box. How do we obtain these limsup and liminf? please clearly explain the way to get these limsup and liminf

thank you for helping.

Comment: The definition of $\liminf A_n$ can be interpreted as the set of the $w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that exist a $n$ such that $w \in A_m$ to all $m \ge n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's show that $\liminf A_n = C_0$ where $C_0 = \{(x,y) : x^2+y^2<1\}$ and $\bar{C}_0 = C_0 \cup \partial C_0$.

Observe that  $\liminf A_n$ can be interpreted as the set of the $w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that exist a $n$ such that $w \in A_m$ to all $m \ge n$. So, let $w=(w_1,w_2)$ a point of $C_0$. Can you see that the circles "converges" to $C_0$? I mean, can you convince yourself that for this $w$ exist a $n$ such that $w$ is in all circles $A_m$ for $m$ large enough?

But what happens with the points on the border of $C_0$, well, they can belong to all circles at the same time because the centers are changing his position. If you take $w$ in the border of $C_0$ but on the left of the origin, for large $m$ it won't belong to $A_m$ when $m$ is even...

To the $\limsup A_n$ remember that it is the set of the $w$ which belongs to infinitely many $A_m$'s ...

Hope this can help!